# MEAN + Passportjs (Facebook) - How do I handle the passport callback with angular without redirects by the server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest, passport.js, passport-facebook

I am in the midst of building a sample authentication app using the MEAN Stack + Passport (for facebook). I would like the server to not be coded for a particular type of client (angular in this instance). I want the passport module to return the status and the data and let the client decide what has to be done in each case?

```
// facebook -------------------------------

  // send to facebook to do the authentication
  app.get('/auth/facebook',
    passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope : 'email' })
  );

  // handle callback
  app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', function(req, res) {

    passport.authenticate('facebook', function(err, user, info) {

      if (err) { return res.json(err) }
      else if (user.error) { return res.json({ error: user.error }) }
      else { return res.json({ redirect: '/profile', user: user }) }

    })(req, res);

  });
```

I am not sure how should I handle the callback in angular since there is no success handler on this route since facebook is calling that endpoint and not angular.

Thanks a lot for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `stateChangeStart` if you are using `ui-router`:

Assuming the page where the user will sign in with Facebook is called /singin with a state of singin, you can trigger this event and handle the next state :

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', (event, next, params, fromState) => {
                    Auth.promise.then(() => {
                        // Look for a redirection state and default to homepage
                        if ($rootScope.isLoggedIn && fromState === "singin") return $state.go("whatever")
                    })
                })
```

also to prevent any default redirection when this condition is true, you can use :

```
event.preventDefault()
```

so you code will looks like this :

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', (event, next, params, fromState) => {
            event.preventDefault()
                    Auth.promise.then(() => {
                        // Look for a redirection state and default to homepage
                        if ($rootScope.isLoggedIn && fromState === "singin") return $state.go("whatever")
                    })
                })
```